# Ruby error reporting in multithreaded environment

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am attempting to write a multithreaded program in Ruby. Errors that occur inside the thread don't report an error message to stdout. I have pared my code down to a minimal program to demonstrate.

In the first example, I create an error in the main block with a meaningless statement:

```
puts "hello"
blah
my_thread = Thread.new do
end
sleep 1
```

In this case the error is reported normally:

> $ ruby bin/test.rb
>  
>   $ hello
>   $ bin/test.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`blah' for main:Object (NameError)

However, if I put the error-causing call inside the thread:

```
my_thread = Thread.new do
  puts "hello"
  blah
end
sleep 1
```

no error is reported:

> $ ruby bin/test.rb
>  
>   hello

If I move the `puts` statement to after the error-causing call it never gets executed, so the error must be halting execution (of the thread).

I tried using exception handling as well - neither of the following echo an error to stdout:

```
my_thread = Thread.new do
  begin
    puts "hello"
    blah
  rescue StandardError => msg
    puts "Error: " + msg
  end
end
sleep 1
```

or:

```
begin
my_thread = Thread.new do
    puts "hello"
    blah
end
rescue StandardError => msg
  puts "Error: " + msg
end
sleep 1
```

I've tried including the better_errors gem in the hope that it 'just works' like it does in Rails projects that have it, my results are no different.

I'm also trying to debug the program in my IDE (RubyMine) but breakpoints inside of the threads never get hit.

Comment: thanks for the tip - the link you shared answers my question

Answer (score 0):

If you [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-i-join) the thread, you will get the error message.

```
my_thread = Thread.new do
  puts 'hello'
  blah
end
my_thread.join  # <-----
```

output:

```
hello
t.rb:3:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `blah' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Thread#value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-i-value) (it calls `Thread#join`).

According to the `Thread#join` documentation:

> ...
>
> Any threads not joined will be killed when the main program exits. If
>   thr had previously raised an exception and the abort_on_exception and
>   $DEBUG flags are not set (so the exception has not yet been processed)
>   **it will be processed at this time**.